# When and why do we need the `wait` command on bash?

Tags: bash, wait

Doesn't the bash shell already run the commands one by one and wait for the executed command to finish? So when and why do we need the `wait` command?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You use `wait` if you have launched tasks in background, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
task1 &
task2 &
task3 &
wait
echo done
```

In this example the script starts three background tasks.  These will run concurrently in the background and the `wait` will wait for all three tasks to finish.  Once `wait` returns, the script continues with processing the `echo done`.

---

As pointed out in comment `wait` can be given a job number (`wait %3`) or a pid (`wait 1234`). While it is easy ( using `job` or `ps` ) in interactive bash to find those, it might be more difficult in batch mode.

Comment: Adding to this, you can use `wait` to wait on specific background jobs (pass a PID for the job), and when doing so it will return the exit status of the job when it exits. This is exceedingly useful for more complex asynchronous programming, as well as waiting for all background jobs to exit before exiting the script.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn: Your tip would be complete if you could state how to get the PID of an & job.